# My substring is working but i'm getting an extra letter at the end from the ending word

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
SUBSTRING(LEFT(shortnote, CHARINDEX('Additional Comments:', shortnote)), 
CHARINDEX('Patient Instructions:', shortnote) + LEN('Patient Instructions:'),LEN(shortnote))
```

I'm getting the result with a bit of space and the letter A from 'Additional Comments' in all of the result. 
How can i get rid of that extra letter. I don't mind any space i just want to get rid of the extra letter. The value I'm getting is between patient instructions and additional comments
Thank You

Comment: Could you show a couple example strings and the desired substring?

Answer (score 2):

```
SUBSTRING(
    LEFT(shortnote, CHARINDEX('Additional Comments:', shortnote)-1), 
    CHARINDEX('Patient Instructions:', shortnote) + LEN('Patient Instructions:') , LEN(shortnote))
```

Comment: i get invalid length parameter when i added the -1

Answer (score 1):

You have to go through `charindex() - 1`.

`charindex()` returns the index at which the search term begins, so to eliminate it you need to move 1 character left.

Comment: I keept getting ivalid length parameter could it be that one of the rows does not have that test that I'm using in the substring.

Comment: I would wrap it in a case statement that checks if `charindex()` returns zero. Then if there are values that do not contain the string you are looking for you can handle those.

Comment: If `charindex('Additional Comments:', shortnote)` returns zero then it doesn't exist and you will need to use an integer larger than the size of the field for the third param of `substring`. You might need to nest case statements if the other charindex can return zero.

Comment: So I just realized some of the rows don't have the words I'm using or might have one or the other. The majority are fine. I don't know how else to write this. It works without the -1 but I get that letter at the end.

Comment: Try: `case when charindex('Patient Instructions:', shortnote) = 0 then
  case when charindex('Additional Commments:', shortnote) = 0 then shortnote
    else substring(shortnote, 1, charindex('Additional Comments:', shortnote) + len('Additional Comments:') - 1)
  end
  when charindex('Additional Comments:', shortnote) = 0 then substring(shortnote, charindex('Patient Instructions:', shortnote) - 1, len(shortnote))
  else substring(shortnote, charindex('Patient Instructions:', shortnote) + len('Patient Instructions:') - 1, charindex('Additional Comments:', shortnote) - 1)
end`

Comment: That may not be exactly right but the thing to do in SQL is to check the `charindex` of both strings. If either or both return zero then the `substring` parameters need to be adjusted. `charindex` returns the index at the beginning of the search text. The above, if not right, should get you on the right track.